# Excel VBA array value not storing to variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA. I can do basic coding which is mostly what I need. But recently I got stuck with the following.

I have defined an Array and populated it successfully

```
Dim WS1(89, 17) As Variant
```

Next I want to get the minimum value from pat of the array for which I have used the following

```
 MoC = 100
 For n = 0 To 89
    For m = 7 To 14
     If WS1(n, m) < MoC Then MoC = WS1(n, m)
    Next m
 Next n
```

The `MoC` returns "0", but when I debug in step with `(CTRL+F8)` I can see that the last value of `WS1(n,m)` after the loop contains a different value. I am struggling to see why cant I store the array value to `MoC` (which is defined as "`Double`", I have tried "`Variant`" as well).  Im not getting any error, just a "0" value.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Really need to see what you're populating WS1 to check with. Do you have a `0` in the array somewhere? Your code isn't getting the last value - it's getting the lowest value in SOME of the array (you only check `7` to `14` of the second dimension. When I run your code with a 1 as the lowest value, `MoC` returns 1 which is correct. When I stick a `-200` in the array position `0,8` - it correctly returns -200.

Comment: I haven't fully understood the question yet. Could you please post the data for `WS1`? The code you have written is pretty much a `MIN` function for the given array and `MoC` will (at the end) hold the smallest available value which is in that array. So, if your smallest value is `0` then there is not surprise that `MoC` is in the end `0`. Yet, note two things: (1) a variant array adjusts for each item automatically. So, this array may contain strings and integers and doubles. If any item is stored as a string then the `Val()` for that item will be `0`.

Comment: @user1274820 many thanks for your reply and effort, the array doesnt hold any '0' value, which I can confirm. However, there are String items as as Ralph mentioned, I changed the MoC type to Double and that sorted it!

Comment: @Ralph Many thanks for your reply and suggestion. As replied to to the comment above, the issue was in the Variant type with String data. Thanks for pointing out, Ive sorted the problem by changing the MoC type.